# Iterate over rails active record model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

How can I iterate over each product_category_id and return an array of modifier_id that belong to product_category_id?

Here is my db layout:

```
id  product_category_id modifier_id time_stamp
1         7                     5               NULL
2         7                     4               NULL
3         7                     54              NULL
4         7                     55              NULL
5         8                      6              NULL
6        93                      7              NULL
7        48                      5              NULL
8        48                      4              NULL
9        48                     55              NULL
10       48                     54              NULL
11       11                      2              NULL
12       11                      1              NULL
13       11                      10             NULL
14       11                      44             NULL
```

https://gist.github.com/ggeorgiev1/aaed6de2643c16bef0a7

So result should look similar to this:
{:product_category_id => 7, :modifier_id => [5,4,54,55] }

Thank you

Comment: What is your table name?

Comment: It is product_category_default_modifiers

Comment: @Pavan Any help appreciated ! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok with a format such as

```
{ 7: [5, 4, 54, 55] }
```

You could do:

```
result = Hash.new {|k, v| k[v] = [] }

ProductCategoryDefaultModifiers.all.each do |it|
  result[it.product_category_id] << it.modifier_id
end

puts result
```

Comment: Will this code iterate through each product_category_id? So result would be: { 7: [5, 4, 54, 55] } { 8: [6] } { 93: [7] }

Comment: Yes, it will iterate over all the record you have in this table

Comment: I get different output: #<ProductCategoryDefaultModifier id: 156, product_category_id: 18, modifier_id: 6, time_stamp: nil>, #<ProductCategoryDefaultModifier id: 157, product_category_id: 18, modifier_id: 8, time_stamp: nil>, #<ProductCategoryDefaultModifier id: 158, product_category_id: 32, modifier_id: 2, time_stamp: nil>, #<ProductCategoryDefaultModifier id: 159, product_category_id: 32, modifier_id: 1, time_stamp: nil>]

Comment: That's the output of the block, what you want is contained within the `result` variable ! `puts result`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [#group_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)

```
ProductCategoryDefaultModifiers.all.group_by do |record| 
  {:product_category_id => record.product_category_id}
end

#=> {:product_category_id=>7} => [#<ProductCategoryDefaultModifier id: 1, modifier_id: 5>, ...]
```

Have in mind for big data set is better to use a database [group](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group)

Answer (score 0):

Just to have array of modifiers for product category = 7

```
modifiers = ProductCategoryDefaultModifier.select(:modifier_id).where(product_category_id: 7).pluck(:modifier_id)
```

or you can have them all in a hash where key will be product_category_id

```
ProductCategoryDefaultModifier.all.group_by{|pcdm| pcdm.product_category_id}
```